# I want to add the home directory to the favorites directories, how can I do it?

Tags: macos, mac

I want to add the home directory to the favorites directories, how can I do it?

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just drag the directory to the left sidebar:

First, you can new open a fonder, then Goto -> Goto Directory, write the `/Users`:

[image]

Then you can drag it:

[image]